# Binary permissions in romfs

Tags: linux, permissions, disk-image

I inherited an old system and I am still getting a hold of how the system works. Its a custom linux running built on AT91. We build a romfs and package in a bunch of binaries that gets installed upon flashing. I have been building as a root because I that is how it was inherited and done in the past. The binaries that get packed into the romfs are listed in a Makefile with individual file  privileges/permissions.

When the romfs gets flashed and all the binaries get installed they have the permissions set to root:root. I understand `romfs-inst.sh` script does set some permissions through the many options it provides and those are being set right.

I need to be able to install the binaries are someuser:somegroup and I am sure there is no `chown` kind of option in the `romfs-inst.sh`. How else do I change the owner and group of the binaries.

Comment: Issue can be closed as this has been answered on a other forum.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683041/binary-ownership-in-a-romfs-package